# How to export query result in a csv file from phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am running a query in PHPMyAdmin. The query is fine. it's showing the correct result.

I want to export that result in a CSV file. It's not on the local server. It's on the webserver

This is my query

```
SELECT notices.id, notices.gazette_notice_id, notices.notice_code, notices.company_number, notices.publication_date, companies.company_name, companies.registered_address_town, companies.registered_address_postcode, companies.sic_1, sic_codes.description, sic_codes.division, sic_codes.section, insolvency_practitioners.name as practionar_name, insolvency_practitioners.company as practitioner_company, insolvency_practitioners.address as prac_address, insolvency_practitioners.phone  FROM notices
LEFT JOIN companies ON notices.company_number = companies.company_number 
LEFT JOIN sic_codes ON companies.sic_1 = sic_codes.code
LEFT JOIN notice_insolvency_practitioners ON notices.id = notice_insolvency_practitioners.notice_id 
LEFT JOIN insolvency_practitioners ON notice_insolvency_practitioners.insolvency_practitioner_id = insolvency_practitioners.id
Where notices.publication_date >'2020-05-01' and notices.publication_date < '2020-05-31'
```

In the phpmyadmin window at the bottom of the result pane, I can see an export link. but if I click on export that allows me only to export the notice table not the result.

[image]

I don't want to create a frontend window for it. just want to export the result in CSV file from PHPMyAdmin

I have checked the questions in here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239956/generate-csv-based-on-mysql-query-from-phpmyadmin

and  here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

But I have confusion understanding the answers. Cause I am running this query in remote webserver and want to download the file in local machine. And don't want to create any new table for that.

How to export the result in csv file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previously answered correctly here:
https://serverfault.com/a/435443

The answer:

1. Execute your sql query in the SQL tab of phpMyAdmin.
2. After execution, scroll down the page and look for “Query results operations”
3. Click “Export” link from the above and you will get the page to export all the results of the queries to desired format. That’s it.

Note: The resulting Export page has 'Dump all rows' Selected, but it actually only exports the results of your query. - This can cause confusion (phpMyAdmin 4.9.4).

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the export function?  Click the `format` drop down and select `csv`

[image]

[UPDATE] OK, I see what you are after.  I have just tested this other way of doing it and it works. Same sort of thing, but at the bottom of your list, select all records and then click export then choose the format.

You can test it by first viewing the output as text before exporting it to a file.

[image]

Comment: If I click on export the result does not export. I can only export the whole database and or one  table. Not the result of the query.